# How can I get a list of Google Maps' "Starred places" to show on the map in my Android app?

Tags: android, google-maps

In the Google Maps app I can add an address to "Starred places" (that I assume are saved to my Google account). Is there a way to access those places from my app? By accessing I mean getting their coordinates and names.

Comment: Did you by any chance figure this out?

Comment: @Flyview No, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

The actual Stars disappear from map sometimes now with the newest update to the Google Maps android app.  My fix: I star and then un-star any random place. My starred places all return, till I close app.  hope that helps till Google Maps fixes problem.